# Verify domain on mailchimp when emails are received by SES and stored in S3

Tags: email, email-bounces, amazon-ses

I have setup a domain in Amazon SES. I can both send and receive emails from/to this domain. Received emails are saved in a S3 bucket.

I can successfully send an email to *whatever*@*mydomain* and I can see it in my S3 bucket.

Still, all the verification emails sent from Mailchimp are not received. The first email seems to be sent correctly (despite the fact I do not receive it), all the following email result in the following Bounce Error message.

> We're having some trouble delivering to [mydomain]. Looks like the verification email might've bounced.

Any Clue about it?

Is there a way to whitelist IP's or sending domains in Amazon SES?

Comment: *Is there a way to whitelist IP's or sending domains in Amazon SES?* seems like the wrong question, because it shouldn't be necessary.  *"The first email seems to be delivered correctly (despite the fact I do not receive it)"* What does that mean?  It can't both be delivered and not delivered.

Comment: Mailchimp prompt me with a "Your verification email is on the way!" the first time I ask for the confirmation message, but I do not receive it. At the second try it gives me the error message specified in the question. I will update the Q to be clearer.

Comment: They are probably just saying that it's "on the way" because they've enqueued it locally.  It's not good practice to try to actually do anything meaningful with an email message in the high-availability path of a web site, so I would assume the first-attempt appearing different in the UI would not actually be meaningful.  *"I can successfully send an email"* ... from where are you sending the test that's working?  Can you mention your domain so we can take a look at things?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to DNS propagation. Amazon SES was initially set only to send email, then I added the MX record to receive emails and forward them to S3. The MX record acctually took around 48hrs to propagate.